# InvalidCastException in constructor when passing the right parameters

Tags: c#, exception, casting, datarow

So I've got this method that creates an object fom a `DataRow`:

```
public Comment CreateComment(DataRow row)
{
    if (row == null) return null;
    var id = (int) row["CommentPk"];
    var song = (int) row["SongFk"];
    var user = (int) row["AuthorFk"];
    var text = (string) row["Content"];
    var parent = (int?) row["ParentFk"];
    return new Comment(_provider, id, song, user, text, parent);
}
```

And the constructor of `Comment` is:

```
public Comment(Provider provider, int id, int songid, int userid, string content, int? parentId)
```

It does crash on the constructor line. I can step (`F11`) to it:

[image: Exception Screenshot]

Comment: Are you debugging through the release build by any chance? I suggest you log `row["CommentPk"]?.GetType()` etc (for all the values).

Comment: The DataColumns of the ROW object you are casting to INT, are most likely not INT.

Comment: They are int and allow a DBNull. I can pull up a screenshot if needed, but 100% sure. It also would crash on that line then I think.

Comment: That exception is either coming from the lines *above* the return statement, or from inside the Comment constructor itself.

Comment: Well if anything is `DBNull`, then casting to `int?` etc would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems to be a problem with the nullable column `ParentFk`.
Instead of

```
var parent = (int?) row["ParentFk"]
```

I used:

```
var parent = row["ParentFk"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)row["ParentFk"];
```

I've used `DataRow`s with nullable columns before but this weird exeption never happened, and it always became null.

**Edit:**

Use this:

```
var parent = row.IsNull("ParentFk") ? null : (int?)row["ParentFk"]
```

Comment: It shouldn't - a cast from an `object` reference of `DBNull.Value` to `int?` *should* fail.

Comment: I've worked with this for half a year and this is the first time it did. Or I simply forgot I had to do this.

Comment: I suspect you've used some other approach, but obviously we can't tell what that was. Note that `row.IsNull("ParentFk")` is somewhat cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I handle this situation by using an extension method to check for null/DBNull

```
int? i = row["CommentPk"].ToNullableInt();


public static int? ToNullableInt(this object value)
{
    if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
        return null;

    return Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

Comment: Just make sure if you're going to put extension methods on `object`, the root of everything, that you confine it to a limited namespace.

Comment: Yes, I have that method in a Helper class that is referenced with a `using` statement